# Zoombox from Xceed WPF Toolkit not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, xceed

I am experimenting with the `Zoombox` control from Xceed, but I am having trouble getting it to respond to mouse wheel or pan events. Nothing happens when I use these inputs. Am I missing something in my code or configuration?

https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit

```
<Window x:Class="UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"

        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="700">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:Zoombox MinScale="0.5" MaxScale="100" >
            <Grid Width="600" Height="400" Background="Yellow">
                <Ellipse Fill="Blue" />
            </Grid>
        </xctk:Zoombox>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define `DragModifiers` and `ZoomModifiers`. Default values are `Ctrl` and `Shift` keys. So use the combination `Shift`+**MouseWheel** for zooming and use `Ctrl`+**LeftButton** for panning.

[image]